# Как пунктами select сделать названия имеющихся баз?

Tags: phpmyadmin, html, php

Нужно для личной работы с различными своими базами написать программку, но мне нужно организовать выбор таблиц, баз и их полей. как их названия вывести в select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
    $res = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");
?>
<select name='databases'>
<?php
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
         echo "<option value=".$row['Database'].">".$row['Database']."</option>";
     }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: выдал
>Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in

Comment: все исправила. Изменила:
echo "<option value=".$row['Database'].">".$row['Database']."</option>";

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется вы копаете не в том направлении, мне кажется это делается так:
1) анализ того что пользователь выбрал в 1 селекте и отправка аяксом данных
2) принятие данные с выборка данных для 2го селекта и вставка в него.

Comment: да я так, в принципе,  и сделала. Просто не знала как для первого select имена баз вывести.